# Jquery get to another page

Tags: jquery, get

I know that there is simple solution which i know but i couldn't remember now.

I want to use get method of jquery but not asynchronous or synchronous. I want to post whole page.
Below i go to 'myurladress'.

```
$('<a>').attr('href','myurladress').trigger('click'); 
/// :) i want to achieve same effect but shortly :))
```

Comment: You don't want it to be `synchronous` or `asynchronous`? ...I *think* those are the only two options available, for most Ajax solutions...

Comment: I wish to learn of this zen programming technique that is neither synchronous nor asynchronous.

Comment: `window.location = 'http://www.example.com';`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to hazard a guess that you want to know how to redirect to another page using JavaScript, in which case you'd use `window.location`. For example:

```
window.location = 'http://www.example.com';
```

Typically this is a bad idea, but there are a few niche cases where this can be useful. Especially when dealing with a *different* window handle (popouts etc.).

Answer (score 0):

```
$("<a>").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();  //prevent the default behaviour of the link
window.location="http://www.whereEverYouWntToGo.com";  
});
```